# How to turn a list into a dictionary?

Tags: python

Input:

```
["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red"]
```

Output

```
["Red":3, "Blue":2, "Yellow":1, "Green":1
```

The value is the amount of times the color popped up.

Comment: Use collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red"]
my_dict = {}
for i in my_list:
    if i in my_dict:
        my_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        my_dict[i] = 1
```

Comment: Might not be correct if case sensitivity is an issue.